# Binding to second image in database

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a database with multiple properties (houses), and each property can have multiple images to go with it. I have a listbox that stores the properties and when I select any property it populates textboxes with the properties information. I can populate an image control with the properties image, but only if one image exists.

In other words, I can see the image fine, it binds fine, and it stores correctly. But when I have more than one image I cannot figure out how to bind to another image. For instance, I want to have 3 images and be able to set each image to a different picture in the database. i thought something like this would work to show the second image but it doesn't...

```
<Image DataContext={Binding Images} Source={Binding [2].ImageData} />
```

My question is: How do I bind to a specific item in a database that contains multiple items. I want to bind to a certain image (I know it will exist so don't worry about validation etc).

Comment: your question is how to get multiple images from database or how to show? please show some xaml code, how do you show one image?

Answer (score 1):

You should bind images using any [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) based control. So it will automatically pickup multiple images if those will be provided by Data source and single Image as well.

Supposing that House class exposing images as `List<Image>` you can bind to a specific item using Binding Path property indexer:

```xml
   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Images[0]}" ToolTip="First Image" />
   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Images[1]}" ToolTip="Second Image" />
```

[MSDN Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx):

> Use the Path property to specify the source value you want to bind to:
>
> - Indexers of a property can be specified within square brackets following the property name where the indexer is applied. For
>     instance, the clause Path=ShoppingCart[0] sets the binding to the
>     index that corresponds to how your property's internal indexing
>     handles the literal string "0". Multiple indexers are also supported.
> - Indexers and subproperties can be mixed in a Path clause; for example, Path=ShoppingCart.ShippingInfo[MailingAddress,Street].
> - Inside indexers you can have multiple indexer parameters separated by commas (,). The type of each parameter can be specified with
>     parentheses. For example, you can have
>     Path="[(sys:Int32)42,(sys:Int32)24]", where sys is mapped to the
>     System namespace.

Comment: I am fairly new to xaml and wpf, but from reading that code, wouldn't that just display the items in a list. I should have mentioned I already know how to do that, my issue is that I need to have 3 seperate image controls placed in different locations around the window/form.

Comment: @Jeremy : does house always has maximum three images?

Comment: Cheers for the update. Unfortunately however it still does not work. Maybe it will help if I explain the situation more. I have set the data context of the entire window to be of... code' DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBoxProperties}" 'code' What this does is enable me to simply Databind to each property of any selected house. E.g the address text box has binding like... 'code' <Textbox Source={Binding Address}/> 'code'.

Comment: My entity database has a property table and image table. A property has attributes like address, id, price etc. Each property can have many images. Each image has an ID, Property_Id, and Imagedata attribute(which stores the bmp image in binary using a converter).